# Angular JS Owl-date-time Calendar (Disabling the Sunday)

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, user-experience, disabled-input, owl-date-time

So I want create input calendar for the user but condition is user Shouldn't allowed to Select Sunday as a day.

So Can I Disable it in Owl-date-time in Angular JS

User Shouldn't able to select Sunday as a day while clicking on calendar.

For E.G
If user only can select the day from Monday to Saturday but not Sunday

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.